# Finding appropriate text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
   <div class="product-name">
                        CLR2811
                    </div>
```

I want to **scrape** this Product name. My Code :

```
ProductTitle = page_soup.find("div",attrs = {'class':'product-name'})
```

This Should Probably return me the right things i-e CLR2811 but when I print ProductTitle its returns me.

```
<div class="product-name">
                            
                        </div>
```

Just the name is missing
URL = http://www.coolline-group.com/product-details.php?pid=5a3c8ac755d2f

Comment: You need the text. I suppose you want this. `print(ProductTitle.text)`

Comment: I have tried them all .text .get_text() all of them are just returning a null string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @[AlexDotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6833134/alexdotis) pointed you, you need to use the element's text attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})
url = "http://www.coolline-group.com/product-details.php?pid=5a3c8ac755d2f"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

name = soup.find("div",attrs = {'class':'product-name'})
print (name.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
CLR2811
```

Comment: @SharyarVohra don't post thank you comments. You thank the author by accepting and/or upvoting. These kinds of comments will be deleted soon [Should “Thank you” comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/995714)